# Pourquoi n'utilise-t-on pas d'article dans « en tous sens » ou « de tous pays » ?

Tags: en, absence-d-article, tout-tous

Quand on apprend le français en tant que langue étrangère, normalement, on découvre deux utilisations du mot « tout ». Le premier signifie « l'intégralité », par exemple, « j'ai appris **tous les mots** » = j'ai appris l'intégralité de ce que j'avais à apprendre. Là, on voit l'article.

Le deuxième signifie « n'importe quel », par exemple, « **toute discrimination** est interdite » = n'importe quelle discrimination, qu'elle soit basée sur X, Y ou Z, est interdite. Là, il n'y a pas d'article.

Mais depuis j'ai rencontré les exemples suivants :

• *Elle courait **en tous sens**.* J'imagine que « tous » signifie « l'intégralité » ici, que la femme courait dans toutes les directions possibles. Alors, pourquoi pas d'article ?

• *Il possédait des souvenirs par dizaines, **de **tous** pays***. — Même question.

Answer (score 4):

L'absence d'article défini dans les deux exemples a des raisons différentes.

**Elle courait en tous sens**
Le *Bon usage* (Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition) dit que :

> *en* s'emploie rarement avec l'article défini : *en l'* et *en la* se trouvent, soit devant des noms masculins à initiale vocalique, soit devant des noms féminins, à peu près uniquement dans quelques locutions toutes faites. en l’honneur de, en l’absence de, en l'état, en l'espace de, en l’espèce, en occurrence,  [...]
> L'usage a remplacé *en le*, *en les*, par *au(x)*, *dans le*, *dans les*.

Le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) fournit une explication historique:

> Une servitude grammaticale fait que, théoriquement, *en* ne peut pas s'employer devant les formes de l'article défini : le, la, les. En ancien français, l'article masculin *le* − primitivement *lo* − se combinait par [enclise](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/enclise) avec la préposition *en* pour donner les formes *el*, *en*, *ou*, puis *au* par confusion avec la forme née de la combinaison de la préposition *à* et de l'article masculin.

*[*En tous sens*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_tous_sens)* est une locution adverbiale, on peut dire aussi *dans tous les sens* pour exprimer exactement la même chose, et après *dans* on emploie l'article défini.
Il y a d'autres locutions adverbiales sur le même modèle :
*en tout lieu* (ou *en tous lieux*), *en toutes choses*, etc...  Le fait qu'il y ait l'adjectif indéfini *tout* entre *en* et le nom ne change rien à la non présence de l'article défini.

**de tous pays**
Même si de *tous pays* est possible dans cette phrase, on peut aussi dire *de tous les pays*, l'omission de l'article est ici une tournure littéraire.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette explication détaillée, ça répond largement à ma question !